# How to change a foreign key field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here are my models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gs_collectors, dependent: :destroy

class GsCollector < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_one :application, dependent: :destroy

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gs_collector
```

Here's my factories:

```
  factory :application do
    ....
    association :gs_collector
    association :dust_type
  end

  factory :gs_collector do
    ...
    association :project
  end

  factory :project do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Project#{n}" }
    contact_name 'John Customer'
  end
```

The Application model used to belong_to Project, so I just used a migration to change project_id to gs_collector_id in the db.  But, now I get this error when trying to run any of my tests (even on units/controllers that have no relation to the application model):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'project' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `applications` (`project`, ....
```

Why am I getting this error?

If I add this line back in to my Application model:

```
belongs_to :project
```

Everything works good again.  But it shouldn't be necessary anymore.

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure the migration was successful ? double check if the db schema has actually changed, and may be restart your processes and then check again, also did you run db:migrate on your test db also ?

Comment: Yes, the migration was successful.  I did run a db:migrate and db:test:prepare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I had a fixtures file that was created by the scaffold generator.  Once I removed the fixtures file, everything worked great.